# ASP.NET MVC: parameter is not passed during URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I defined the below routes to have friendly urls in my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CreateChildRoute",
    url: "Admin/MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild/{parentId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem", action = "CreateChild", parentId = UrlParameter.Optional }
); 
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] {"ProjectManager.Controllers"}

);
```

However when I call: `http://localhost:46813/Admin/MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild/23` 
A null value is passed to controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateChild(int? parentId){
  .....
}
```

But calling `http://localhost:46813/Admin/MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild?parentId=32` 
Works with no problem and passes the parameter as it supposed to be.

P.S. `Admin` is a defined area in my application.
Here is output of Route Debugger for `http://localhost:46813/Admin/MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild?parentId=2`:
[image]

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. How are you generating the urls?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I generated above URLs by hand to test application, however are there any other methods for tests? I tried RedirectToAction and stuff like this, which will create URLs in this pattern (`.../CreateChild?parentId=32`), as an example: `@Html.ActionLink("Create New Item", "CreateChild", new { parentId = @ViewBag.ParentID }, null)`

Comment: It would need to be `@Html.ActionLink("Create New Item", "CreateChild", "MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem", new { parentId = @ViewBag.ParentID }, null)` which will work fine and generate `..../Admin/MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild/23`. If its not, then there is something else you have not shown us causing the problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this was brought from Index View of same controller so Adding controller name was not necessary however I tried to explicitly define Controller however it did not made any changes.

Comment: And your claiming its generating `...?parentId=32` instead of `.../32`? (I cant reproduce that)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yep, it is like that, however I tried to remove `/Admin` part, after that paramter passed correctly and `.../32` generated! I don't know how to define `Admin` area in RouteMaps or ActionToLinks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113417/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-vsb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see your route table looks to be correct, there's a typo in there but it seems to be pretty consistent throughout so I'm guessing that's not a problem.

Contrary to what teo van kot says you always want to start with the most specific routes first and have the more general ones come last as only the first route to match will be used.

A useful tool I've used to debug my routes is the [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) from Phil Haak.  It lets you see what route was chosen and, more usefully which parameters were mapped, and can be installed via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/%20NuGet)

Comment: I put output of route debug, does it help you?

Comment: You've got another route in there that matches before the one your interested in.  It's the default route for your Admin area, /Admin/{controller/{action/{id}.  If you are going to use areas I suggest that you move your route from RouteConfig.cs into the config file for your area.  It'll be in the RegisterArea method in the Areas\Admin\AdminAreaRegistration.cs file that you want all your admin routes to go in.  And again it will need to come before the default route.

Comment: yeah, that is right, I had a default route for area in `AdminAreaRegistration.cs` :)

Comment: Awesome, just move your route into there and it should work as you want! If that's now working I'd appreciate you marking this as the answer :)